# How to shoot bullet in any direction in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game in which the player rotates automatically with moving keys. I want my player to fire a bullet in the direction which it is facing. The problem is that whenever I shoot, the bullet only goes upwards even when the player is facing down, right or left.
This is my Player script.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 3.5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _bulletPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _bulletPoint; // the point from which bullet fires 
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CalculateMovement();

        // if i hit the space key
        // spawn gameObject

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(_bulletPrefab, _bulletPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        
    }

    void CalculateMovement ()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * verticalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector2 movementDirection = new Vector2(horizontalInput, verticalInput);
        float inputMagnitude = Mathf.Clamp01(movementDirection.magnitude);
        movementDirection.Normalize();

        transform.Translate(movementDirection * _speed * inputMagnitude * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        if (movementDirection != Vector2.zero)
        {
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, movementDirection);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This is bullet script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bulet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 8.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: you tell the bullet to move "up * speed * deltatime" .. so yes, it moves up.. this was your choice

Comment: Yes, you are right i figured it but how i can fire in all direction if i write left it only fire in left.

Comment: you would do best to set the item on creation to point the same direction as your player then use transform.forward

Comment: The bullet only fire and states there doesn't move anywere

Comment: is your "bulet" script on it?

Comment: bullet script on what??

Comment: um, your bullet? the one that tells it to move

Comment: instead of `Instantiate(_bulletPrefab, _bulletPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);` spawn it with the correct rotation? Like e.g. `Instantiate(_bulletPrefab, _bulletPoint.transform.position,  _bulletPoint.transform.rotation);`

Comment: **derHugo**Thanks for answering it worked, its amazing. Thanks again.